# Facebook dependency into Flutter app crashes

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Whenever I import a facebook dependency (`flutter_facebook_login: "^1.1.1"`) into a pubspec.yaml  in the app that I am developing, and I launch the app, it says "App has stopped", and whenever I remove it, it works.

Comment: Please add the output of `flutter doctor` and the output the app produces when it crashes.

Comment: I/Process ( 4936): Sending signal. PID: 4936 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To get things up and running, you'll have to declare a pubspec dependency in your Flutter project. **Also some minimal Android & iOS specific configuration must be done, otherise your app will crash.**"

Did you include all configurations correctly? Depends on which device you are using you have to make sure that the Android or iOS configuration is set up correctly.

See https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_login